# react swiper slidesPerColumn doesn't working

Tags: swiper.js, tailwind-css, react-swiper

I want to show three items vertically in one slide.
[image: description]

The official document of react swiper says to use `slidesPerColumn`.

So, I try to use it, but, it says Swiper doesn't have `slidesPerColumn` properties.

How can I organize the slide as shown in the following picture?

Additionally, I'm using React 18.